# Mongo shell in Windows 7 "unicode text could not be correctly displayed"

Tags: mongodb, windows-7, cmd, mongo-shell

I am using Windows 7 64 bit and I have English and Greek language installed for my keyboard.
If I switch to mongo shell and I try to write a UTF Greek character, I get this error

```
"Unicode text could not be correctly displayed.
Please change your console font to a Unicode font (e.g. Lucida Console)."
```

and it exits from the mongo shell.

Also when I type `db.names.find()` it displays the contents of the `names` collection but the UTF characters are messed up.

I can write UTF characters in regular cmd prompt without problems.

Comment: Same exact problem here... with italian keyboard mongo shell is a mess... Console2 / Poweshell / Power cmd / Cygwin - winpty .... None of these worked! I really have no idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem for my system by doing this procedure and changing font to `Lucida Console`. Before that it was set to `Raster Fonts`.

1. Open cmd
2. Right-click on the title bar
3. Choose Properties
4. Select the `Font` tab and from there choose the `Lucida Console` font and press `ok`.